# Inserting template date tag in Django

Tags: django

I'm attempting to insert a date tag in my Django template, and I've read the Django documentation but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I've got in my latest attempt, which basically came directly from my understanding of the docs and example within them:

```
{{ datetime|date:"l" }}
```

Now, I haven't done anything in Python to create a view or a model using any importation of datetime, and the Django documentation didn't implicitly state I needed to beforehand.

I'm using Django 1.10.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter, you start with a variable that is a date or datetime. For example, if you had a view,

```
from datetime import date

def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'my_date': date(2017, 1, 1)})
```

then you could use the `date` filter on the `my_date` variable in the template:

```
{{ my_date|date:"l" }}
```

If you want to display the current date in the template, you can use the [`now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#now) template tag.

```
{% now "l" %}
```

Comment: AH! That's exactly what I needed - however, if I use the "now" method - it's saying "Thursday" ... except it's Wednesday - still, I better understand what the process to make it work is as well - Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a timezone issue - it was 00:24 UTC on Thursday when you wrote that comment.